# CronScheduledRoutePolicy not starting the route at specified time

Tags: apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I created a `CronScheduledRoutePolicy` to start and fire my route daily at 15:30PM for fetching xml from some website and storing it in db like below

```
CronScheduledRoutePolicy startPolicy = new CronScheduledRoutePolicy();
startPolicy.setRouteStartTime("0 30 15 * * ?");

from("direct:quatzRoute")
    .routePolicy(startPolicy)
    .log("Route started")*/
    .to("http4://mywebsite/today.xml")
    .log("Response ${body}")
    .convertBodyTo(String.class).process(new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange e) throws Exception {
            log.info("Before Logging the xml");
            ExchangeRateBean.writeToDB(e);
            log.info("After Logging the xml");
        }
    })
    .log("Xml Stored in DB")
    .to("mock:result");
```

In console it shows route started on deployment of bundle. But at specified time (for testing gave current time) my job is not done. No log messages also.

Is there anything else i need to do??

Answer (score 3):

That is a policy for activating the route, so incoming messages to direct:quatzRoute work at that time.

Use one of the following instead to fetch data at a specific time

http://camel.apache.org/quartz.html

http://camel.apache.org/quartz2.html

Comment: Yes, for example by loading a property from a property file and then use
from("quartz:" + PropertyConfig.getQuartzTime()) would be a solution